# gzip softlocks every midnight during nginx log rotation, causes kernel panic

Tags: ubuntu, logrotate, gzip, linode, kernel-panic

Some of our servers run on Ubuntu 18.10. They host a few Node.JS services receiving TCP connections as upstream from nginx, as well as a websocket implementation in Dotnet Core. It's a fairly simple setup sysadmin-wise.

One of the machines started behaving weirdly lately after upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 to 18.10. A kernel panic will occur almost every midnight. The machine usually handles around 10'000+ connections real-time without any problem. It's a pretty powerful setup.

**From syslog (`ryk` is my sudoer user) :**

```
Jun 29 00:00:02 localhost CRON[23415]: (ryk) CMD (/home/ryk/dev/downloadadscript.sh)
Jun 29 00:00:02 localhost CRON[23419]: (ryk) CMD (cd /home/ryk/ampcache && node narcity.index.js 200)
Jun 29 00:00:02 localhost CRON[23420]: (ryk) CMD (cd /home/ryk/ampcache && node mtlblog.index.js 200)
Jun 29 00:00:02 localhost CRON[23421]: (root) CMD (test -x /usr/bin/certbot -a \! -d /run/systemd/system && perl -e 'sleep int(rand(43200))' && certbot -q renew)
Jun 29 00:00:02 localhost CRON[23426]: (ryk) CMD (/home/ryk/dev/uploadsbackup.sh)
Jun 29 00:00:02 localhost CRON[23412]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Jun 29 00:00:04 localhost CRON[23409]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Jun 29 00:00:04 localhost CRON[23408]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Jun 29 00:00:05 localhost logrotate[23418]: error: destination /var/log/nginx/access.log.1.gz already exists, renaming to /var/log/nginx/access.log.1.gz-2019062900.backup
Jun 29 00:00:11 localhost CRON[23413]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Jun 29 00:00:58 localhost kernel: [65787.092653] watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#11 stuck for 26s! [node:8764]
Jun 29 00:00:58 localhost kernel: [65787.092695] watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#3 stuck for 30s! [node:8715]
Jun 29 00:00:58 localhost kernel: [65787.092735] watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#8 stuck for 32s! [gzip:23478]
Jun 29 00:00:58 localhost kernel: [65787.092739] Modules linked in:
Jun 29 00:00:58 localhost kernel: [65787.092746] watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#12 stuck for 27s! [node:23489]
Jun 29 00:00:58 localhost kernel: [65787.092752]  joydev
Jun 29 00:00:58 localhost kernel: [65787.092758] watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#1 stuck for 37s! [nginx:29255]
Jun 29 00:00:58 localhost kernel: [65787.092763] watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#10 stuck for 41s! [nginx:29256]
Jun 29 00:00:58 localhost kernel: [65787.092765] Modules linked in:
Jun 29 00:00:58 localhost kernel: [65787.092768] watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#13 stuck for 37s! [node:3327]
Jun 29 00:00:58 localhost kernel: [65787.092770]  input_leds
Jun 29 00:00:58 localhost kernel: [65787.092773] Modules linked in:
Jun 29 00:00:58 localhost kernel: [65787.092775]  joydev
```

And then, unreadable kernel dump until reboot 19 minutes later.

[image: syslog kernel panic dump screenshot]

```
Jun 29 00:19:53 localhost kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 4.18.0-25-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-025) (gcc version 8.3.0 (Ubuntu 8.3.0-6ubuntu1~18.10.1)) #26-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 24 09:32:08 UTC 2019 (Ubuntu 4.18.0-25.26-generic 4.18.20)
Jun 29 00:19:53 localhost kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-25-generic root=/dev/sda ro console=ttyS0,19200n8 net.ifnames=0
```

We use the default `logrotate` routine to make sure logs have a decent size, and are compressed for archiving. For `nginx`, it runs every day. Our `nginx` config does not store access logs except for one route which is not busy at all. Those are never heavier than 20MB before compression.

**From `/etc/logrotate.d/nginx` :**

```
/var/log/nginx/*.log {
    daily
    missingok
    rotate 14
    compress
    delaycompress
    notifempty
    create 0640 www-data adm
    sharedscripts
    prerotate
        if [ -d /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate ]; then \
            run-parts /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate; \
        fi \
    endscript
    postrotate
        invoke-rc.d nginx rotate >/dev/null 2>&1
    endscript
}
```

There are a few things happening at the same time at midnight, but 16 CPUs should be more than enough to provide enough power for all of those tasks.

- 200 requests are sent to AMP caches to clear latest pages
- Certbot will renew HTTPS certs if needed
- logrotate will, well, rotate logs
- rsync will save that day's uploaded images and files to a backup server
- A Node.JS service will invalidate old cache entries in RAM

At first, I tried delaying those tasks by a few minutes, but `logrotate` or `gzip` would still manage to crash the entire server at some point.

A couple information about the server :

- Hosted with Linode
- Handles millions of requests every day
- 16 CPU, 64GB RAM
- Main processes : NodeJS, Dotnet Core, nginx, a few C++ routines
- There's an additional disk attached to it for backups
- There are no lag spikes or any abnormality during the day
- We don't run an `express` server, `mongoose`, or other overused libraries
- Most of the requests don't even reach any of the services; nginx will serve cached / static files
- CPU is low, RAM is usually below 30% usage before cache invalidation

`uname -a`

> Linux localhost 4.18.0-25-generic #26-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 24 09:32:08 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Any idea why `logrotate` or `gzip` would cause the entire machine to softlock? Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

**update #1**

I just noticed that according to `htop`, there's a lot of stealtime happening (CPU yellow bars) while gzip is compressing the logs.

**update #2**

It happened once again today. Here is the last `syslog` output before the server panicked.

```
Jun 30 00:00:04 localhost logrotate[18277]: error: destination /var/log/nginx/access.log.1.gz already exists, renaming to /var/log/nginx/access.log.1.gz-2019063000.backup
```

Here's the last output of `/var/log/kern.log`

```
Jun 29 00:00:58 localhost kernel: [65787.092735] watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#8 stuck for 32s! [gzip:23478]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your virtual machine may be on a physical server that is having hardware problems. Shut down the VM and then start it again, and Linode should start it on a different hypervisor.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I asked Linode to move our VM to a different rack, and they confirmed it's now running on a less busy machine. Apparently we're a "whale". Let's hope it fixes it!

Comment: unfortunately we just had an other crash. Same reason, same time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using joydev, try to unload/remove joydev module.

```
List module and remove

$ sudo lsmod|grep joydev
$ sudo modprobe -r foo
You can also use the rmmod command, which is simple program to remove a module from the Linux Kernel:
$ sudo rmmod joydev
```

Make sure joydev module is unloaded/removed.